# Make "tap to add priority senders" disappear

Tags: sms, system-apps

I have recently updated the OS of my phone, and since then I have the following "Tap to add priority senders." on my SMS app which I don't like, it just uses screen space.

How can I remove it?

Android version: 4.4.2
Galaxy S5

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Example Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it, click on the three vertical dots on the top-right of your screen.

Then, go to Settings.

Scroll down to "Priority senders" and unmark the tick box.

Hope it helps.